# Unable to update correct total price using triggers

Tags: sql, db2

I can't get the correct total price for the transaction table.
total price for T001 suppose to be 1000 but it calculate together with T002 and become 2000.
Can anyone have a look at my trigger? Thankyou :D
I would also like to ask about how to set cardinality for my table as each transaction can only has at most 3 purchase detail?

```
//My trigger
create trigger calc_totprice 
after insert or delete on purchase_detail 
for each row mode db2sql 

begin 

    if inserting then
    update transaction 
    set tot_price = (select sum(purchase_price) 
    from purchase_detail, transaction 
    where purchase_detail.trans_id = transaction.trans_id); 

    elseif deleting then 
    update transaction 
    set tot_price = (select sum(purchase_price) 
    from purchase_detail, transaction 
    where purchase_detail.trans_id = transaction.trans_id);
end if; 
end

//transaction table
TRANS_ID CON_ID CUS_ID TRANS_DATE TRANS_STATUS TOT_PRICE
-------- ------ ------ ---------- ------------ ---------
T001     CN01   CU001  2017-01-01 SUCCESS        2000.00
T002     CN01   CU001  2017-01-01 SUCCESS        2000.00

//purchase_detail table
PURCHASE_ID SEAT_ID TRANS_ID PURCHASE_PRICE
----------- ------- -------- --------------
P001        1       T001             500.00
P002        2       T001             500.00
P003        1       T001             500.00
P004        2       T002             500.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want correlated subqueries:

```
if inserting then
    update transaction 
        set tot_price = (select sum(purchase_price) 
                         from purchase_detail
                         where purchase_detail.trans_id = transaction.trans_id
                        ); 

elseif deleting then 
    update transaction 
        set tot_price = (select sum(purchase_price) 
                         from purchase_detail
                         where purchase_detail.trans_id = transaction.trans_id
                       );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!